# Can we stay invertible while approximating linear maps in Sobolev spaces?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, sobolev-spaces, matrix-rank, exterior-algebra

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ be an open bounded domain. Fix an integer $1<k<d$.

Let $f \in W^{1,k}(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^d)$ be a **continuous map** with $\det df > 0$ a.e.

Consider the map $\Omega \to \text{End}(\bigwedge^k \mathbb{R}^d)$ defined by $x \to \bigwedge^k df_x $. Since $\det df > 0$ a.e. $\bigwedge^k df_x \in \text{GL}(\bigwedge^k \mathbb{R}^d)$ a.e.

> Think of $\text{GL}(\bigwedge^k \mathbb{R}^d)$ as a subset of $\text{End}(\bigwedge^k \mathbb{R}^d)\cong \mathbb{R}^{\binom{d}{k}^2} $. With this identification in mind, suppose that $$\bigwedge^k df \in C\big(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^{\binom{d}{k}^2} \big) \cap W^{1,k}\big(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^{\binom{d}{k}^2} \big).$$
>
> Do there exist $u_n \in C^{\infty}\big(\Omega,\text{GL}(\bigwedge^k \mathbb{R}^d)\big)$, such that $u_n \to \bigwedge^k df$ in $W^{1,k}_{loc}\big(\Omega,\text{GL}(\bigwedge^k \mathbb{R}^d)\big) $?
>
> I am also interested in a weaker  result: Are there $u_n \in C^{\infty}\big(\Omega,\text{End}(\bigwedge^k \mathbb{R}^d)\big)$, such that $u_n \in \text{GL}(\bigwedge^k \mathbb{R}^d)$ a.e. **and**
> $u_n \to \bigwedge^k df$ in $W^{1,k}_{loc}\big(\Omega,\text{GL}(\bigwedge^k \mathbb{R}^d)\big) $?

I don't really need the $u_n$ to be defined on all $\Omega$. It is enough that for every arbitrarily small compact ball in $\Omega$, there would be a neighbourhood where such a sequence $u_n$ would be defined.

Of course, there are always $u_n \in C^{\infty}(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^{\binom{d}{k}^2})$ such that $u_n \to \bigwedge^k df$ in
$W^{1,k}\big(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^{\binom{d}{k}^2} \big)$. (just approximate each component of $\bigwedge^k df$ separately). The question is whether or not we can choose the approximations of the different components in such a way that their "combined" map will stay invertible almost everywhere.

The problem is that **it is not always true** that $\bigwedge^k df_x \in \text{GL}(\bigwedge^k \mathbb{R}^d)$ for *every* $x \in \Omega$. The rank can fall on a subset of measure zero.

**If we knew $\bigwedge^k df \in \text{GL}(\bigwedge^k \mathbb{R}^d)$  everywhere then the answer would positive.** This follows from the facts that "being invertible" is an open condition, and that continuous Sobolev maps can be *approximated uniformly* by smooth maps in the strong Sobolev topology.

In more detail, let $K \subseteq \Omega$ be compact. Since we assumed $\bigwedge^k df \in C\big(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^{\binom{d}{k}^2} \big) \cap \text{GL}(\bigwedge^k \mathbb{R}^d)$, the map $\psi:x \to \bigwedge^k df_x$, considered as a map $K \to \text{GL}(\bigwedge^k \mathbb{R}^d)$, is continuous. Thus $\psi(K) $ is compact. This implies that $\text{dist}\big(\psi(K),\partial \text{GL}(\bigwedge^k \mathbb{R}^d)\big)>0$, where $\partial \text{GL}(\bigwedge^k \mathbb{R}^d)$ is the boundary of the set $ \text{GL}(\bigwedge^k \mathbb{R}^d)$, considered as a subset of $ \text{End}(\bigwedge^k \mathbb{R}^d)$.

Now, consider each component of $\psi(x)=\bigwedge^k df_x \in \text{End}(\bigwedge^k \mathbb{R}^d) \cong \mathbb{R}^{\binom{d}{k}^2}$. We can approximate  each component, using mollification (on an open subset of $\Omega$ containing $K$). Since each component is a continuous function, the mollifications *converge uniformly* to the components on compact subsets, and in particular on our $K$. This implies that from a certain point in the mollified sequence, $\text{dist}(u_n,\bigwedge^k df)<\text{dist}\big(\psi(K),\partial \text{GL}(\bigwedge^k \mathbb{R}^d)\big)$, so the $u_n$ are invertible, as required.

Comment: With the assumption of $\bigwedge^k df \in W^{1,k}$ (which doesn't seem natural to me) I can't tell for sure what is happening here. Preserving invertibility while approximating Sobolev maps is hard. To my knowledge, all the results of this kind in dimensions $n>2$ are negative: there are tricky counterexamples by Hencl and coauthors, such as [here](https://jyx.jyu.fi/handle/123456789/51921).

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting. In my case, however, I assumed more than $\bigwedge^k df \in W^{1,k}$. I also assumed the minors are continuous functions. This implies that one can approximate $\bigwedge^k df $ uniformly, so we do have an invertibility of the mollifying sequence, at least if we want a local result. (You can see my answer below for details). I hope I will be able to explain soon where my assumption $\bigwedge^k df \in W^{1,k}$ comes from. (I admit it looks unnatural without some additional context).

Comment: Actually, on a second thought I was too hasty. By my assumptions, I only have invertibility of the "$k$-minors map" $\bigwedge^k df$ almost everywhere, and not everywhere. This causes a problem with the naive strategy I used. (An explanation has now been inserted into the question).